# Representation of skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, cross-product

It is well known that there is an identification between the Lie Algebra of $3x3$ skew-symmetric matrices and $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the hat map
$$ \hat{ }:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathfrak{so}(3),\; \hat{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -v(3) & v(2) \\ v(3) & 0 & - v(1) \\ -v(2) & v(1) & 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$
My question is: is there some way to generalize this hat map to higher dimensional skew-symmetric matrices? Or, even if not with the hat map, since the dimension of the space of $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrices is $n(n-1)/2=m$, is there a "standard" way to identify $skew(n)$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Well the identification on the level of vector spaces is easy. The problem is that the Lie algebra bracket, when pulled over, will not be something as easy as the cross product on $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Ah okok, yes sure as vector spaces the identification can be done in many different ways but is easy. So it becomes intricate when trying to preserve the Lie bracket? Thank you